# Formatting cell to show text in a text box. Excel Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

[image: Excel Sheet]

I have this sheet. The Product details section and the price section are not visible because of large amounts of text in them. When I manually make the size equal to the text..It becomes very ugly and almost incomprehensible. I saw an image where the data in the cells was shown inside a text-box with the cell size only slightly larger. You can scroll the text box within the cell. How can I do this for all the rows in these columns. Thanks.

Comment: Row by row? In a text box on each row? Not with Excel 2007. This is a case of "wrong tool for the job".

Comment: @teylyn Should I use a different program to view this altogether?

Comment: See https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/show-contents-of-cell-when-hovering.515724/

Comment: I have fixed this by manually setting the cell height/width and wrapping text. Looks ok.

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @help-info.de Didn't really feel like an answer, So, I didn't. :). Sort of a work around. Also, My question was about the text-box.

Comment: Are you looking fur label? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-label-or-text-box-to-a-worksheet-6905d5da-fad4-432e-87ea-001f3ecd6cd6

Comment: @AbhishekRai,, possibly you are talking about the List box,,,!!